# How can I simplify my nom parser?

Tags: parsing, rust

I'd like a recommendation on how I can improve the function `unquoted_string` below - specifically **is there a better way to combine the parsers I have to achieve the desired goal?**

Strings in this language are defined by [YANG RFC 7950 Section 6.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6). The excerpt relevant to unquoted strings is:

> An unquoted string is any sequence of characters that does not contain any space, tab, carriage return, or line feed characters, a single or double quote character, a semicolon (";"), braces ("{" or "}"), or comment sequences ("//", "/*", or "*/").
>
> Note that any keyword can legally appear as an unquoted string.
>
> Within an unquoted string, every character is preserved.  Note that this means that the backslash character does not have any special meaning in an unquoted string.

What I've got so far is:

- `yang_char`: a predicate to match any unicode character that is permitted in the language
- `yang_char_unquoted`: a predicate which filters out the exceptions described in the excerpt above
- `unquoted_string`: a parser for a valid unquoted string - **this is what I'd like input on**

In words, unquoted string matches the longest sequence of characters not containing:

- any of the excluded characters above, or,
- any of the digraphs `//`, `/*` and `*/`

The main concern I have is that each of the `take_until` calls requires doing a substring search, which seems inefficient. What I really want to do is walk the (hopefully not very long) string returned by the first `take_while1` call until I find a matching digraph.

**Code**

```
extern crate nom;

use nom::{
    branch::*,
    bytes::complete::*,
    character::complete::*,
    combinator::*,
    error::{ErrorKind, ParseError},
    multi::*,
    sequence::*,
    IResult,
};

fn yang_char(c: char) -> bool {
    match c as u32 {
        0x00000009 => true,
        0x0000000a => true,
        0x0000000d => true,
        0x00000020..=0x0000d7ff => true,
        0x0000e000..=0x0000fdcf => true,
        0x0000fdf0..=0x0000fffd => true,
        0x00010000..=0x0001fffd => true,
        0x00020000..=0x0002fffd => true,
        0x00030000..=0x0003fffd => true,
        0x00040000..=0x0004fffd => true,
        0x00050000..=0x0005fffd => true,
        0x00060000..=0x0006fffd => true,
        0x00070000..=0x0007fffd => true,
        0x00080000..=0x0008fffd => true,
        0x00090000..=0x0009fffd => true,
        0x000a0000..=0x000afffd => true,
        0x000b0000..=0x000bfffd => true,
        0x000c0000..=0x000cfffd => true,
        0x000d0000..=0x000dfffd => true,
        0x000e0000..=0x000efffd => true,
        0x000f0000..=0x000ffffd => true,
        0x00100000..=0x0010fffd => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

/// Variant of yang_char accepting only characters allowed in unquoted
/// strings (see `unquoted_string` for details).
///
/// N.B. This function handles only single characters, so doesn't
/// deal with the comment sequences mentioned in `unquoted_string`
fn yang_char_unquoted(c: char) -> bool {
    match c {
        ' ' => false,
        '\t' => false,
        '\n' => false,
        '\r' => false,
        ';' => false,
        '{' => false,
        '}' => false,
        _ => yang_char(c),
    }
}

/// Per the above, this may contain any valid YANG character, except:
/// - Whitespace (space, tab, line feed, carriage return)
/// - Single or double quotes
/// - Semicolon
/// - Open or close braces ('{' or '}')
/// - Comment sequences ('/*', '//', or '*/')
///
/// In an unquoted string, every character is preserved, which means
/// that backslash has no special meaning.
fn unquoted_string(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let (_, i_tmp) = take_while1(yang_char_unquoted)(i)?;

    let len = match alt((take_until("//"), take_until("/*"), take_until("*/")))(i_tmp) {
        Ok((_, val)) => val.len(),
        Err(nom::Err::Error((val, ErrorKind::TakeUntil))) => val.len(),
        err @ Err(_) => return err,
    };

    Ok((&i[len..], &i[..len]))
}
```

**Tests**

```
fn test_unquoted_string() {
    assert_eq!(unquoted_string("abcd"), Ok(("", "abcd")));
    assert_eq!(unquoted_string("1.234"), Ok(("", "1.234")));
    assert_eq!(
        unquoted_string("a-test-string__.1234"),
        Ok(("", "a-test-string__.1234"))
    );
    assert_eq!(
        unquoted_string("a-test//-string__.1234"),
        Ok(("//-string__.1234", "a-test"))
    );
    assert_eq!(
        unquoted_string(" "),
        Err(nom::Err::Error((" ", ErrorKind::TakeWhile1)))
    );
}
```